# Second forward difference $\Delta^2y$ for $y = (x-1)^4$ at $h = 1$

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I am trying to determine the second forward difference $\Delta^2y$ for $y = (x-1)^4$ at $h = 1$.

I came up with the solution $\Delta^2y = 2(6x^2+1)$ both by using
$y = (x-1)^4$ directly and by using its expansion $y = x^4 - 4x^3 +6x^2 - 4x +1$.

The textbook gives the answer as $\Delta^2y = 12(x-1)^2$. (I do see that this solution is $\frac{d^2 x}{dy^2}$, which can't be coincidental...)

I did the algebra longhand for $x^4 - 4x^3 +6x^2 - 4x +1$ but used Wolfram Alpha (online) for $(x-1)^4$ and they both agreed on the answer, so I believe it must be my conceptual understanding rather than my algebra which is faulty. Can someone enlighten me?

For the interested, this is problem 9.3.2 of *Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers, Second Edition* by R.W. Hamming. (The problem is on page 153 of the Dover reprint; unfortunately, this section/page is not in Google Books, but a pirated PDF is not too hard to locate elsewhere on the Web.)

The difference formulas given in the textbook are $\Delta y(x) = y(x + h) - y(x)$ and $\Delta^n y(x) = \Delta[\Delta^{n-1}y(x)]$.

Answer (score 1):

All of what you wrote means that $$f''(x) \approx \frac{\Delta_h^2[f](x)}{h^2} =  \frac{f(x+2h) - 2 f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^{2}}$$ which is the standard formula for the second order forward difference (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)).

Applied to $f(x)=(x-1)^4$, after development, simplifications and factoring, $${f(x+2h) - 2 f(x+h) + f(x)}=12 h^2 x^2-24h^2\left(1-h\right) x+h^2(12 -24 h+14 h^2)$$ making $$f''(x)\approx 12  x^2-24\left(1-h\right) x+(12 -24 h+14 h^2)=12(x-1)^2+24hx-(24-14h)h$$ For sure, if $h\to 0$, you recover $12(x-1)^2$; but, if this is not the case, say $h=1$, the result is quite different.

Comment: Claude, thanks for the clear response.

In the final formulation of your answer, $f''(x)=12(x−1)^2+24hx−(24−14h)h$, substituting in $h=1$ yields the solution $12x^2+2 = 2(6x^2+1)$ which was my proposed answer.

In short then, it appears that my solution was correct and the answer given by the textbook is in error.

I also appreciate your fully spelling out the formulation of $f''(x)$ at the beginning of your answer and the concluding observation that as $h→0$ then $\Delta^2f → f''$ -- this is a good insight that I did not pick up from the textbook.